# Why aren't single-command pipelines executed in subshells?

Tags: bash

My `bash` man page for version 4.4.19 says:

> **Pipelines**
>
> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`.  The format for a pipeline is:
>
> `[time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|||&] command2 ... ]`

Sure. That makes sense. Then, later in that section:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

Also reasonable, and easily proved:

```
$ pwd
/Users/ravron
$ ls | grep src  # yes, src _does_ exist
src
$ cd src | true  # cd in subshell has no effect on parent session
$ pwd
/Users/ravron
```

However, I noticed that the definition of a pipeline, above, is worded such that even a simple command is a pipeline. After all, in the syntax, everything except `command` is optional:

```
[time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|||&] command2 ... ]
```

Now, of course, running even single commands — in `man bash` terminology, "simple commands" — in subshells would be really quite useless. `cd` wouldn't work, variable setting wouldn't work, etc. However, the reality — that simple commands, despite matching the syntax for a (rather degenerate) pipeline, are not executed in subshells — appears to be at odds with the man page. In list form, here's my understanding:

- The syntax for pipelines means that simple commands are also pipelines.
- The man page says that the commands in a pipeline are run in subshells.
- Simple commands are not run in subshells.

What am I missing, or is this an admittedly inconsequential bug in `man bash`?

Comment: If you want real normative documentation that's been written with language-lawyers fighting over it, that should be http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html. Note that there, the single-command case *is* explicitly described as a pipeline.

Comment: ...however, see section 2.9.1 of that standard, subsection "Command Search And Execution", exempting behavior of built-ins from the usual requirement of `execve()` happening in a "separate utility environment".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual is just imprecise. The POSIX spec (section 2.12) is more explicit (bold face added by me):

> Additionally, each command of a **multi-command** pipeline is in a
>   **subshell** environment; as an extension, however, any or all commands in
>   a pipeline may be executed in the current environment. All other
>   commands shall be executed in the current shell environment.

`bash`, by default, takes the position of implementing each of those subshells as a subprocess. (The `lastpipe` option introduced in `bash` 4.2 lets the final command execute in the current shell environment/process.)

The shell's grammar says that a pipeline can consist of one or more commands, but the shell's semantics distinguish between pipelines of one command and pipelines of two or more commands.

Answer (score 1):

The manual never defines the word "subshell". While you might intuitively assume that a subshell is always a subprocess of the original shell, the degenerate case of a single command uses the original shell process as the subshell.

Some other shells go further, always running the last command in a pipeline in the original shell.

Comment: Doesn't "each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process" contradict this?

Comment: @ravron, separate *from the other pipeline components*, not separate *from the invoking shell*.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686872/sub-shell-diffferences-between-bash-and-ksh